# How to change the Overflow icon to white in Action bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, styles

Hello can any one help me in this how to change the overflow icon to white colour I have tried a lot but it is not coming here is my code can any one help me. Help will be appreciated. Here is the code I think so their is only a minor mistake I'am unable find the mistake please help me.

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.Text</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="android:background">#336699</item>
         <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.OverFlow</item>
    </style>
     <style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.OverFlow" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/menu</item>
</style>
    <style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.Text" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">25dp</item>
</style>
<style name="myTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/myTheme.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">#ffffff</item>

    </style>

    <style name="myTheme.ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">#336699</item>
         <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/myTheme.ActionBar.OverFlow</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/myTheme.ActionBar.Text</item>
    </style>

    <style name="myTheme.ActionBar.OverFlow" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/menu</item>
</style>

    <style name="myTheme.ActionBar.Text" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
         <item name="android:textSize">23dip</item>

          <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-condensed</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    </style>



</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your theme dark:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dark">
```

or you can change the actionbar theme instead:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Comment: it is showing error i think so i dont have this theme in my theme combo box

Comment: thank you for that but i need to have my overflow image over their as i mentioned in the code above

Comment: So is your icon showing at all?? and if so what is the color problem ??